# display product present only in both category 1 and category 2

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, product-list

I am trying to display only those products which are present in both category 1 and category 2
or in other words
only those products which are present in both parent category and its sub category
I tried this:

> ```
> $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
>         ->getCollection()
>         ->distinct(true)
>         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
>         ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
>         ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',$parentcategory)
>         ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',$subcategory ); Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
> ```
>
> `foreach($collection as $product){ echo $product->getId(); }`

EDIT:I used this to get product id but its giving error  of getId on non-object

Comment: Assume it's not returning the product you want?

Comment: no it's returning me error saying getId() on non-object in mage/../product/collection.php

Comment: There you go. It's a collection of products. You should loop the collection and call that attribute within the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it can be achieved by intersecting the collection result arrays.

As this is not straightforward and default Magento doesn't provide any facility to intersect collections, we have to do it manually as below:

```
$_productCollection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->distinct(true)
 ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
 ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
    'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('eq' => 7))
 ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

 foreach($_productCollection1 as $product)
    $arr1[] = $product->getId();

 $_productCollection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->distinct(true)
 ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
 ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
    'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('eq' => 8))
 ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

 foreach($_productCollection2 as $product)
    $arr2[] = $product->getId();

 $result = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
 foreach($result as $product_id):
    $productLoaded = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    //do something with $productLoaded
endforeach;
```

Now you will have only products present in both categories 7 and 8.

**Hope this will help.**

Comment: this code is causing my page to loading and loading..

Comment: above code is working only if  I am passing only one category but not working when passing two

Comment: Updated my complete answer, please check and let me know.

Comment: still infinite loop i have visited ur link and already tried all possiblities from there

Comment: Updated my answer again, this is the last resort. It is working in my local system.

Comment: Nice! Even I did the same way and got the solution only instead of array_intersect I use in_array() to filter and create  a new collection

Comment: I didn't tried your code but it is similar to my code in concept so accepted  your answer

Comment: Ok thanks, you can try this anytime. Really strange as Magento by default doesn't provide anything for filtering with two or more categories with `AND` condition.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->joinField(
        'category_id',
        'catalog/category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        null,
        'left'
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(
        $id1,
        $id2
    )));
$collection->getSelect()->having('count(entity_id) > 1')->group('entity_id');
```